# Encrypting and Decrypting NSF file using C#

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I want to  **Check whether a NSF file is Encrypted**  or not (using C#).
And if it Encrypted i want to  **Decrypt those NSF Files**  and Save them on different path.
Currently i am using " Domino.dll".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you drop into the "C API" for Notes, there is a method named NIFDbIsLocallyEncrypted, which returns a boolean. There is some sample code [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/46dom.nsf/c21908baf7e06eb085256a39006eae9f/63a6174bef5eb92380256ba7004a9e8f?OpenDocument).  For background on the Notes C API Toolkit, see [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/lotus/documentation/capi/)